# Regex in capybara have_xpath

Tags: regex, capybara

I have a text changing decoration when it is clicked. In my tests before clicking I want to check whether it's already clicked or not. It changes color, text decoration and href which I want to check through.

As href contains session specific information, so I want to use regex.

```
if page.have_xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"%20Administrators?\")]")
```

This passes even the page has already been updated and Administrators text has changed to something else.

How should I correct the syntax to accept all href containing "%20Administrators?" text. I want add it to if clause as if the page has the link with text Administrators in it.

Before clicking: href="/sometext/%20Administrators?redirect=sometext" 
After clicking : href="/sometext/%20Standard?redirect=sometext"

Comment: What's the question? What pattern should the regex be checking for? What results did you get that were not what you wanted?

Comment: The code i pasted is not correct, i want to know if i am using correct method and how should I correct the syntax to accept all href containing "%20Administrators?" text.

Comment: Aha! `how should I correct the syntax to accept all href containing "%20Administrators?" text`. That seems like the question you need to add to your post. But you also need to show some example text, how you're changing it, and the text after the change.

Comment: Is it possible that `sometext` also contains "%20Administrators", and that's why it still matches after it changes?

Comment: No it does not have it . double checked by using another unique part in the sometext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue you're having here is using `have_xpath` rather than `has_xpath?`.  `have_xpath` returns an RSpec matcher, and as such when used with `if` will always evaluate as true (since it returns an object and hasn't yet actually evaluated any XPath passed in).  `has_xpath?` returns a boolean result of true or false.

```
if page.has_xpath?('.//a[contains(@href,"%20Administrators?")]')
```

The second issue is that your question asks about regex, but XPath 1.0 (which browsers support) doesn't have regex support and your XPath isn't using regex at all (just a `contains` expression). If you actually want to use regex for testing the href (and have better reading code) you should be using the `has_link?` boolean method - along the lines of

```
if page.has_link?(href: /Administrators/)
```

`has_link?` can also verify the visible text of the link too if wanted

```
if page.has_link?('Visible text of the link', href: /Administrators/)
```

Finally, when using XPath with Capybara, 99% of the time you should start your XPath with `.//` instead of just `//` - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap - and is one reason why it's usually cleaner to use CSS and/or the more specific methods provided by Capybara rather than the `xxx_xpath` methods.

One other thing to note is that all of the methods mentioned have waiting behavior by default, so they will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for the page to have a matching link.  If you know the page is stable and just want to immediately know whether or not a matching link exists you might want to pass `wait: false` as an option

```
if page.has_link?(href: /Administrators/, wait: false)
```

Comment: @user3594145 You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so your question gets marked as answered, if it helped you.